# How to use Try Catch to display Login failure for (App.Config) connection string

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, sqlexception

My coding is simplified by using a single line of code to connect to MS-SQL 2008 R2 Databases. However I wish to have a msgbox displayed on login/password failure. Here's the coding.

```
My.Settings.Item("CustomerConnectionString") = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial        
Catalog=customer; uid = temp ; pwd = temp"

<< catch error required >>
```

Thanks.

Comment: what exactly is your question? btw, you may probably better to de-simplify this code just to prevent a simple sql-injection hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First assign the value to app.config connection string:

```
My.Settings.Item("CustomerConnectionString") = "Data Source=FAROOK-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
Catalog= '" & Me.ComboBox1.Text & "'; uid = '" & Me.Login1.Text & "'; pwd = '" & 
Me.Password1.Text & "'"
```

Then use Try Catch Block. If connection fails use yor message box in catch block.

```
Dim sqlCnn As New SqlConnection
Dim connString as string = My.Settings.Item("CustomerConnectionString").value

Try
   sqlCnn = New SqlConnection(connString)
   sqlCnn.open()
   globalConnStr = connString
Catch ex As SqlException
   MsgBox("Login Failed")
Finally
   sqlCnn.close()
End Try
```

Declare globalConnStr as global variable and when you are done with the checking of the login credentials assign the connection string to  globalConnStr. After this you can use the globalConnStr string as many times you want in your program.

Comment: Geek, the above code should work. I'll get back once I have pasted the coded and tested.

Comment: Geek the code works fine. Cannot get .Value from My.Settings.Conn.. so I have used ToString. I am going to tik this post as answered. Thanks mate!

Comment: Welcome. And mark the previous question also as answered if the solution helped. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817040/how-to-display-a-login-failure-messagebox-for-app-config-connection-string

Comment: I shall do that. By the was could you (compare) test the My.Settings.connstring for speed. I find this connection method to be light, so the connection is fast. Thanks & regards.

Comment: Sorry i did not get the question. please elaborate and provide code.

Comment: In My.Settings.Item("Connection string") everything is done for you. Lines such as sqlCnn.open() are not required, enabling a faster connection/application run. Could you use the My.Settings.Item("Connection String") versus the regular connection string to test? If not for security issues, I would key in the settings directly to the App.Config file.